# nodejs https#request fails where identical curl request succeeds

Tags: node.js, curl, https, request, twitter-oauth

I am trying to connect to public stream endpoint of twitter api.

When i ran example parameters i got from twitter api test tool in nodejs i get `401 unauthorized` error below you can see my nodejs example request

```
 'use strict';
const https = require('https');
const qs = require('querystring');
const obj = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="pXZ8xSWvjZjE4UaNntVsCwWPg", oauth_nonce="776f1a4ec0c3ed9ecbfb68aa0f7e2324", oauth_signature="jk8e84V0OcgcepkL7F%2BXt2fAy8o%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1463258508", oauth_token="416282416-vFTMVJCFiRW8G6nwoFhH3OBqrJsKDbIJ93sbOm2a", oauth_version="1.0"'
    },
    hostname: "stream.twitter.com",
    path: "/1.1/statuses/filter.json"
}
https.request(obj,res => {
    res.on("data", d => {
        console.log(d.toString());
    });
}).end(qs.stringify({track:"javascript"}))
```

But if i send this request with curl it perfectly works here is my example curl request

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json' --data 'track=javascript' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="pXZ8xSWvjZjE4UaNntVsCwWPg", oauth_nonce="776f1a4ec0c3ed9ecbfb68aa0f7e2324", oauth_signature="jk8e84V0OcgcepkL7F%2BXt2fAy8o%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1463258508", oauth_token="416282416-vFTMVJCFiRW8G6nwoFhH3OBqrJsKDbIJ93sbOm2a", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

what am i doing wrong ?they are tottaly identical requests.

Comment: `curl` gives you some good debug info, but the `node.js` code doesn't. Can you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-debug to get some debug output? This might show you in what way the requests are not identical

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not calling `curl` first and then reusing the same nonce with node.js, right?

Comment: @mdickin this is just example i create an example from api tools on twitter calling it through curl it works then creating new caling it with nodejs it fails

Answer (score 5):

You can't hardcode the timestamp in the OAuth request. If the code you are presenting is the one you are using then this could be the cause of the problem. I recomend you use the [oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth) package to generate the Authorization header.

Comment: i have a working code for get requests to twitter but the same code fails for streams

Answer (score 0):

Same thing just happened to me, and I ended up using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library to resolve this.

Not sure what is the difference between axios and the built in https request, but the fact is that using axios worked where the https request failed. (and curl worked as well.)

Comment: Well, see where my project bought me :)

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome haha, hi there! Well hope you succeed, that was a real pain working with it, generally speaking. :/